# How to append lists using list comprehension to an exsiting list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to append items to an **existing** list that have been generated by list comprehension as individual lists.

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want the result to look like `[[2], [4]]`

I have tried the following (and other crazy combos of '[]' and '()' and gotten nowhere)...

```
target = []
target.append([r for r in source if r == 2 or r == 4])
print(target)
[[2, 4]]

target = []
target.append([[r] for r in source if r == 2 or r == 4])
print(target)
[[[2], [4]]]

target = []
target.append([r] for r in source if r == 2 or r == 4)
print(target)
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000022F1986E4C8>]
```

Comment: Use the second or third version with `.extend` instead of append. a list comprehension creates **a single list always** and `.append` will always add that **single list**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `.append()`:

```
source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
target = []

target.extend([r] for r in source if r == 2 or r == 4)

print(target)
# [[2], [4]]
```

It's possible to use `.extend()` in this case because it receives an iterable as an argument.

Comment: Thank you all. I gave this answer a tick because it clearly shows what to do but just as importantly it says why.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this list comprehension with `extend`:

```
target.extend([[r] for r in source if r in [2, 4]])
```

And now `target` would be:

```
[[2], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list.extend` method instead:

```
target.extend([r] for r in source if r == 2 or r == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.append()` go for `.extend`:

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5]
target=[]
target.extend([t] for t in source if t==2 or t==4)
print(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = [[r] for r in source if r==2 or r==4]
print(target)
# output: [[2], [4]]
```

If the target list is not empty and you want to append new values, you can try this

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = [[7],[8]]
target.extend([[r] for r in source if r==2 or r==4])
print(target)
# output: [[7], [8], [2], [4]]
```

or

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = [[7],[8]]
target += [[r] for r in source if r==2 or r==4]
print(target)
# output: [[7], [8], [2], [4]]
```